# Meta Pixel Event parameters not showing up on FB Analytics

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-analytics

I am sending SubmitApplication events with some custom parameters, which seem to work according to the Meta Pixel Helper extension, as it seems from my screenshot

[image]

But the events show up on Facebook Analytics as having no parameters, and a message saying "Custom Data not being displayed" appears, which seems relevant but i wonder why it's there, and how i can show my params on Analytics

[image]

This is my code sending the events

```
fbq('track', 'SubmitApplication', { firstName: first_name, lastName: last_name, email: email, phone: phone } );
```

Any hints please?